# How can I download a video file (with dynamically changing link) directly to my server?

Tags: linux, ssh, webserver, ubuntu-12.04, wget

Hy, my question is about transferring videos directly to my web-server so that I don't have to upload them to the server (as it takes time).
I am using WGET tool via ssh on server for this task. WGET is downloading videos which has links (static) like this one:

```
http://pmln-hec.site88.net/CrackMD5SHA1hash.mp4
```

But when I try to download a video from a website like openload.co, I get forbidden 403 error (even when I am using user agent in WGET)
This is the command which I am using:

```
WGET -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0' https://ph2dos.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/lTmwcDbNky0pMsKN/pM06kIyNq7M/Barbie+Princesha+dhe+Kengetarja+e+Popit+%282013%29.mp4?mime=true
```

Output

```
--2016-12-29 13:27:58--  http://ph2dos.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/lTmwcDbNky0pMsKN/pM06kIyNq7M/Barbie+Princesha+dhe+Kengetarja+e+Popit+%282013%29.mp4?mime=true
Resolving ph2dos.oloadcdn.net (ph2dos.oloadcdn.net)... 91.207.102.204, 2a04:9dc0:3:51::
Connecting to ph2dos.oloadcdn.net (ph2dos.oloadcdn.net)|91.207.102.204|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-12-29 13:27:58 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Can you tell me whether it's even possible to download something from such type of (dynamically generated link, I hope I am making sense in it) or not? If it is then where am I going wrong? If this is not the way, can you please give me an alternative way?

```
Note:If I paste the above URL in a download manager like IDM, it's working fine.
```